# Efficient way to get the angle between two vectors in a single plane?

Tags: c++, math, vector, geometry

If I know for a fact that the x and z values of the vectors will be identical,
therefore im only concerned in measuring the 'vertical' angle of from the differences in the y plane, is there a more efficient method to do this compared to computing the dot product?

My current code using the dot product method is as follows:

```
float a_mag = a.magnitude(); 
float b_mag = b.magnitude();
float ab_dot = a.dot(b);
float c = ab_dot / (a_mag * b_mag);

// clamp d to from going beyond +/- 1 as acos(+1/-1) results in infinity
if (c > 1.0f) {
    c = 1.0;
} else if (c < -1.0) {
    c = -1.0;
}

return acos(c);
```

I would love to be able to get rid of these square roots

Comment: One subtle thing: `acos(1) == 0` and `acos(-1) == PI`, neither of them are infinity. The function `acos` is defined in the interval `[-1, 1]`, and beyond this interval, `acos` is *undefined*.

Comment: I'm going to ask a very basic question.  Are you sure you need an angle?  Quite often, I find that when I get an angle, I either convert it back to a vector immediately, or that a straight algebraic solution will work better for what I'm doing.

Comment: I understand where your coming from. Im using this angle to determine whether or not it + another angle is past a threshold or not. Basically it is used to clamp a 3rd person camera's vertical rotation between +90 and -90 degrees (above or below the player)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that your two vectors live at `u = (x, y1, z)` and `v = (x, y2, z)`, and you're interested in the planar angle between the two along the plane spanned by the two vectors. You'd have to compute the dot product and the magnitude, but you can save a few operations:

```
u.v = x.x + y1.y2 + z.z
u^2 = x.x + y1.y1 + z.z
v^2 = x.x + y2.y2 + z.z
```

So we should precompute:

```
float xz = x*x + z*z, y11 = y1*y1, y12 = y1*y2, y22 = y2*y2;

float cosangle = (xz + y12) / sqrt((xz + y11) * (xz + y22));
float angle = acos(cosangle);
```

Comment: `v^2 = x.x + y2.y2 + z.z`, isn't it?

Comment: @FlopCoder: Yep - copy/paste doesn't always go all the way :-S

Comment: awesome! one sqrt() down! Now in another function I do the same thing, except in this case I also know that one of the y values will always be 0, so that knocks out the need for y12 and y22 variables. So it becomes cosangle = xz / sqrt((xz + y11) * xz); Any way to get rid of the final sqrt() with that?

Comment: @user785259: I doubt it, at least not if you want the actual angle, and not the angle-squared. What's the ultimate purpose, though? Maybe you can save some expensive operation elsewhere... (and of course you are familiar with John Carmack's insane inverse square root...)

Comment: I actually was not... im definately going to take a look at that algorithm! Thanks a billion!

Answer (score 1):

If the values of x and z are unchanged, then the calculation is very easy: just use basic trigonometry.

Let the points be `(x, y1, z)` and `(x, y2, z)`. You can find out the angle a vector makes with the ZX-plane. Let the angles be `t1` and `t2` respectively. Then:

```
w = sqrt(x^2 + z^2)
tan(t1) = y1 / w
So t1 = atan(y1 / w)
Similarly t2 = atan(y2 / w)
The angle is (t2 - t1)
```

There's one pitfall: When both x and z are zero, the `tan`s are undefined... but such a trivial case can easily be handled separately.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to avoid the square root.